# Relation between the row picture and column picture

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I am going through Strang's book "Linear Algebra and its applications" and it's written there that, " If n planes have no point in common or have infinitely many points, then the columns lie in the same plane".
This is a very important idea, one that unifies the row and the column picture. Can someone explain to me why this happens? Why is it that when the row picture fails, the column picture fails inevitably?

Comment: I can't understand your question.please inform  me the page number of that book where you have seen it.

Comment: Page 9. 4th edition. 3rd paragraph, written in bold. My question is: Why the column picture fails if the row picture does?

Comment: I assume that row picture fails means that the given planes of the given system of equations does not intersect.So all the rows are the multiple of the 1st row.Now apply row operation to determine that rank of matrix obtained by those rows is 1.So the column has also rank 1.ie.you may assume that all the columns is multiple of 1st column.So we have no solution if the vector of right side does not lies on that plane ie.you can't combine columns to get right side vector,So Column picture also fails.